# How to fill in pandas data frame of unknown size

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty new to Python and I am trying to scrape information of multiple sites which are all of the same structure, but of different length. What I am trying to do is add my information row by row from an empty data frame, like you can do in R by simply calling the indices and R adds a row to the data frame. In pandas however, I can't seem to find a way to create an empty matrix and add a row to it like that, when I try to do

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.iloc[0] = [1,2,3,4]
```

the program presents me with the error message:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I know there are functions like *append* but it doesn't seem to do the work for me.

I find it very weird that i haven't found any information on this on stackoverflow so this may be a duplicate question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain you got 4 columns give them a name first, `columns=[0,1,2,3]`. Then you can use `.loc[]` to append data and if you have your columns defined as integers you can use append too:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0,1,2,3])
df.loc[len(df)] = [1,2,3,4]

rows = [[5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
df = df.append(rows, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
2  1  2  3  4
3  5  6  7  8
```